# Statistical method to compare multiple ratio of averages

Tags: p-value, mean, ratio

What is the best statistical method to use to evaluate the difference between multiple ratio-of-averages (NOT average-of-ratios)?

I have two parameters (P1 and P2) that are changing over time (5 time points).  I want to know if the change in the ratio of P1/P2 over time is significant.  I want to compare the ratio-of-averages (average P1 and P2 first, then find ratio) over the course of the 5 time points, NOT the average-of-ratios (take ratio of each individual P1/P2 first, and then average).  I understand that one can use ANOVA for the latter case...

### But what statistical test can I use to compare the ratio-of-averages over time?

Thanks for your response.  I'll try to be more specific:  I have 50 individuals for whom I am measuring P1 and P2 across 5 time points (t0 through t4).  Over time, the mean P1 of the 50 individuals decreases, as does the mean P2.  I can calculate delta-P1 and delta-P2 for the interval between each of the time points to quantify the average change.  However, the ratio of dP1/dP2 also decreases over time, meaning that P1 is actually changing faster earlier on relative to P2, and then slows down over time.  What I want to show is that the decrease observed in the ratio-of-averages, dP1/dP2, is statistically significant over the 4 intervals between each of the 5 time points (t0-t1, t1-t2, t2-t3, t3-t4).  My understanding is that if I were using the average-of-ratios to calculate these numbers, I could just use ANOVA.  However, I am not, I am using the ratio-of-averages (as explained), and need to know how I show statistical significance.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking for, but I'm not at all sure that you really want to analyse the ratios. What is the question that you would like your analysis to help you answer? Something like "do P1 and P2 vary differently over time?" or "how does the relationship between P1 and P2 vary with time?" might be answered more completely with something other than a test of ratios of means. Have you plotted the data?